# data list move up and down rows jquery

Tags: jquery, datalist

Hi all I am trying to move data up and down from my data list, here is the fiddle which I tried but I am not getting the required one. so can some one help me

https://jsfiddle.net/mwd4ranu/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".up,.down").click(function(){
    var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
    if ($(this).is(".up")) {
        row.insertBefore(row.prev());
    } else {
        row.insertAfter(row.next());
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

When you use parents("tr:first") you actually select the closest tr and not the one you try to move

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".up,.down").click(function(){
    var row = $(this).parents("#dlList > tbody > tr").first();
    if ($(this).is(".up")) {
        row.insertBefore(row.prev());
    } else {
        row.insertAfter(row.next());
    }
  });
});
```

PS : Do not forget to select jQuery as fiddle javascript library

Comment: Hi `Ianis` thanks for the code it is working but i had a change , the list is grouped by and displayed. So when I moving up if I have a text box as the top row it should not be moved. Like wise if I moved down if a text box is found in the next row it should not be moved. Find the update here https://jsfiddle.net/mwd4ranu/